# How to control Parse ACLs on public level

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Parse just updated to V 1.1.0 and this was listed as a change:

> Converted PFACL's publicReadAccess and publicWriteAccess methods to
>   properties.

Now I don't know how to change ACLs on a public level. It used to be this:

```
            acl.setPublicReadAccess(true)
            foo.ACL?.setPublicWriteAccess(true)
```

How do I achieve these effects now?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
acl.publicReadAccess = true
foo.ACL?.publicWriteAccess = true
```